# C++ array memory leak

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

I am making a voxel game and was getting so far until I realized my game was eating my memory very slowly. First of all, I had an array of blocks:

```
Block *blocks[100][100];
```

This was working, but the objects stayed right in the memory and was causing a memory leak. Then I started iterating through the array deleting the objects before reassigning the objects. It was still using up more and more memory, but slower this time. Basically I deleted all of the elements of that blocks array, but I was somehow still getting a memory leak. This is how I was doing it:

```
delete blocks[x][y];
blocks[x][y]= new Block("stone");
```

And like I said, this was still somehow leaking memory. Can someone explain to me what is happening? Thanks.

Comment: Easy way: use smart pointers, or just plain old objects if you can.

Comment: To start with, you might want to look into the use of [smart pointers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory). To continue the leak might be somewhere else, and it might be that the operating system is caching memory so it's actually not a leak. And to end, try to avoid pointer (smart or not) as much as possible.

Comment: @chris Is that in the standard lib?

Comment: It's possible the leak is within the Block objects themselves - members allocated but not deleted, etc.

Comment: If your class `Block` has members which are dynamically allocated, then make sure when deleting a `Block` instance, you deallocate those members properly.

Comment: @SusanYanders, Yes, the C++11 standard library has `std::unique_ptr`, `std::shared_ptr`, and `std::weak_ptr`. TR1 has `std::tr1::shared_ptr`, and Boost has some as well. Do be sure to only use any form of pointer if you really need a pointer, though.

Comment: Also, use something like valgrind to do some memory profiling. It sure will help you find the leaks. Also, you might be suffering of internal fragmentation.

Comment: @phoxis Oooh so my block members need to be deleted in a deconstructor?

Comment: @SusanYanders, Only if they need some form of cleaning up. Again, smart pointers and the like will do it for you. It's collectively called RAII.

Comment: @SusanYanders Are you dynamically allocating any member (with `new`) in the constructor ?

Comment: @phoxis No, just calling functions

Comment: @SusanYanders the rule of thumb is this: for every time you call `new` you **must** call `delete` once (obviously when you no longer need the memory, of course). No more, no less.

Comment: @SusanYanders are those functions allocating any member of the instance of `Block`.
Better have a smart pointer as @chris and @Joachim Pileborg suggests.

Comment: @phoxis actually i dont know my block class extends from another class from another library. that might be the problem. maybe that class dynamically allocates things

Comment: If you check and release the element one by one , there is no reason for memory leaking.Do you check your logic for sure that you do not forget to release someone? You'd better to wrap the array to a manager class which creates and releases and knows every element's status.

Comment: @MIKU_LINK fixed my problem. Hard to explain, I was trying to delete all objects at once but some werent being deleted. My game is working ^_^

Comment: @SusanYanders OK,greate. Can you post the way you try to delete.May be I can learn some thing from your problem.

Comment: I had my deleting correct. The problem was that some elements of the array were never actually deleted, so thats why it kept building up every time i reloaded my array.